# regarding Handsontable conditional Formatting

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I have a Handsontable which contains values and i need apply number format like `$0,0.00` . Using the below code i am able achieve it but if i apply `renderer` to the cellproperty the cell changes with the new style by overwriting the previous cell format.Please tell what mistake i am doing

**Code**

```
function inHeadRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
        Handsontable.TextCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
         td.style.textAlign="left"
         td.style.paddingLeft="1%";
         td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
         td.style.fontSize="10px";
         td.style.fontFamily= 'verdana';
         td.style.background = '#FCFFFA';
         td.style.color = '#0B610B';
    }



cells: function (row, col, prop) {
if($("#handsontable").handsontable('getData')[col,row][num_cols-1] ==="Inflow"){
             cellProperties={
                       type: 'numeric', 
                       format:'0,0.00',
                       language: 'en'


                }

  return cellProperties;
}
```

I want to apply style for the formatted cell Properites

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renderer gets triggered every time changes are made to cell. That is the reason for overriding of formats.

### Update

http://jsfiddle.net/hU6Kz/3519/ is the working code for your reference.

Correction. 
Included the type in renderer

```
inHeadRenderer=function(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
   Handsontable.NumericCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
     td.style.textAlign="left"
     td.style.paddingLeft="1%";
     td.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
     td.style.fontSize="10px";
     td.style.fontFamily= 'verdana';
     td.style.background = '#FCFFFA';
     td.style.color = '#0B610B';
    cellProperties.type = 'numeric';
};
```

Comment: yes i tried it again only the style gets applied but number format doesnt come cellProperties={
        
          type: 'numeric',
                language: 'en',
       format:'0,0.00',
                 renderer:inHeadRenderer
               
               
          }